# Is $\log_p(x^z)=z \log_p(x)$ for $z \in \mathbb Z_p$?

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Let $\log_p$ denote the $p$-adic logarithm and $\mathbb Z_p$ be the ring of integers.

We know that $p$-adic logarithm has no base, but still we have $\log_p(x^n)=n \log_p(x)$ for $n \in \mathbb Z$ and $x \in 1+p \mathbb Z_p$. Here the prime $p$ doesn't mean base. Can we extend the result from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z_p$ ? i.e.,

> Is $\log_p(x^z)=z \log_p(x)$ for $z \in \mathbb Z_p$ ?

---

Let $ \mathcal{C}(\mathbb Z_p, \mathbb Q_p)$ denotes the continuous $p$-adic valued functions, then $\log_p \in \mathcal{C}(\mathbb Z_p, \mathbb Q_p)$. Then
\begin{align} &\mathbb Z \to \mathcal{C}(\mathbb Z_p, \mathbb Q_p) \\ & n \mapsto \log_p(x^n)=n \log_p(x),
 \end{align}
which is continuous map with respect to $p$-adic topology. So I think the maps extends to $$z \mapsto z\log_p(x),$$
in other words, $\log_p(x^z)=z\log_p(x)$.

I appreciate comments.

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: You didn't mention that $(x,n)\mapsto x^n$ is continuous $1+p\Bbb{Z}_p \times \Bbb{Z}\to 1+p\Bbb{Z}_p$ so it extends naturally to $1+p\Bbb{Z}_p \times \Bbb{Z}_p\to 1+p\Bbb{Z}_p$. Composing with $\log_p$ which is continuous gives your result.

Comment: @reuns, I got it. Thanks